# Шаблонизатор PHP

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

У меня есть довольно простой шаблонизатор на PHP:

```
<?php
  define("PATH","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/templater");

  class Templater{
    private $title;
    private $path;
    private $copyright = '&copy;2011 Все права защищенны';
    private $date;
    private $time;

    public function tmp($title,$path=NULL){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->date = date("d.m.Y");
        $this->time = date('H:i:s');

        $tmp = file_get_contents(PATH.'/tmp/'.$this->path);
        $tmp = str_replace('{TITLE}',$this->title,$tmp);
        $tmp = str_replace('{DATE}',$this->date,$tmp);
        $tmp = str_replace('{TIME}',$this->time,$tmp);
        $tmp = str_replace('{COPYRIGHT}',$this->copyright,$tmp);

        return $tmp;
    }
  }
  $templater = new Templater();
?>
```

ну и файле index.php и где надо уже в корне сайта я делаю следующее:

```
require_once 'class/templater.php';
  print $templater->tmp($title,'header.tpl');
  print $templater->tmp($title,'body.tpl');
  print $templater->tmp($title,'footer.tpl');
```

что бы вызвать сам шаблон.

Мне нужно что бы в файлах tpl была возможность использовать php код например

[if()] [/if]
[elseif()] [/elseif] 
[else] [/else] 
[while ()] [/while]
[for()] [/for] 
[include file=""]
[require file=""] 
[switch ()] [/switch]

Ну вот подобие, хоть как главно что бы файл был tpl и в нем можно было использовать php код, буду очень благодарен так как мучаюсь уже не первый день поисками, пожалуйста не предлагайте smarty и другие шаблонизаторы...

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев

> пожалуйста не предлагайте smarty и другие шаблонизаторы..

а что вы хотите ? чтобы кто-то вам шаблонизатор написал ?

Comment: ))) Вам самому надо программировать теги [while] и прочие. Определять в коде их через регулярное выражение. Но это изобретение велосипеда :)

Comment: eicto, я спросил как это сделать можно а не что бы сделали.

Comment: ipriger, а по другому не как нельзя что бы хотя бы без этих тегов можно было вставить PHP код ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, есть ответ - написать парсер, а вообще php  сам по себе шаблонизатор, почему бы просто не использовать include :) а чтобы понять как сделать посмотрите на исходники уже готовых шаблонизаторов и  подумайте, хотите ли вы сделать лучше :)

Comment: > define("PATH","http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/templater");
> $tmp = file_get_contents(PATH.'/tmp/'.$this->path);

????????? Это что, серьезно?

Comment: Шаблонизация - это просто отделение бизнес-логики от логики вывода. Пишите шаблоны на альтернативном синтаксисе PHP и не заморачивайтесь с регулярками и заменами.

Comment: Какова цель всего этого?

    [if(something)]do_something;[/f]

Чем лучше, чем (даже если забить на производительность):

    <?php if(something) do_something; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании file_get_contents для выполнения php конструкций, потребуется дописывать логику замены php подобных команд в шаблонах. В одной из своих наработок решил этот вопрос отправкой всех переменных в шаблонизатор и обращение напрямую к объектам класса в шаблонах.

Код шаблонизатора:

```
class Templater{
    function __construct(){}

    public function AddVariant($var,$name) {
        $this->$name = $var;
    }
    public function Template($TplFile) {
        require_once $TplFile;
    }
}
```

Отправка переменных шаблонизатору:

```
//Инициализируем шаблонизатор
$templater = new Templater();
//Отправляем шаблонизатору переменные
$templater->AddVariant($Content->header, 'header');
$templater->AddVariant($Content->text, 'text');
//Назначаем файл-шаблон
$templater->Template($tpl);
```

Код (примерный) шаблона страницы

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><?php echo $this->header['title']; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $this->header['meta_d']; ?>" /> 
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $this->header['meta_k']; ?>" />
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->text; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ещё один велосипед не претендующий на совершенство, но надеюсь поможет Вам в развитии Ваших навыков.

Comment: А зачем в шаблонах `echo`? Что мешает писать просто `<?=$this->header['meta_d']?>`? 

Кстати, поищите аналогичные классы шаблонизации на базе перегрузки методов - отличное решение, позволяет либо сократить объем вбиваемого в шаблон кода (вместо `<?=$this->header['meta_d']?>` можно писать `<?=$this->meta_d?>`, либо расширить функциональность до преобразования данных к нужному для вывода формату. В свое время за основу брал этот класс - http://myrusakov.ru/php-template.html

Comment: @Равнодушный, мешает вот что, в какой-то момент в 5.2 кажется, сказали что short_open_tags - зло, и стали по умолчанию делать их off, потом спохватились и сказали что `<?= ` это не short_open_tags и будет работать даже если off, но теперь разработчики не знают где будет работать, а где нет (если не закладываются на 5.4) и всегда делают `<?php echo`; 

вот такая история.

Comment: @eicto, в современном мире, чтобы технологии развивались, просто необходимо рекомендовать заказчику поддерживать актуальные версии ПО. При поддержке старых проектов - да, подстраиваемся хоть под php4. Но смотреть на стандарты 5.2, когда 5.6 у входа... Словом, не Вы ли тут вечно ноете, что `mysql_` ой как устарело с версии 5.5?

Comment: eicto написал правильно, не на всех хостах где используется этот вариант шаблонизатора работает short_open_tag. Пришлось писать так чтобы не было мучительно больно править шаблоны при переезде.